# Connecting two ASP.Core-applications (API + Angular)

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

With this post I am looking for suggestions and tips how I should proceed with my development. I am not entirely sure that my setup is doing it in the right way. My setup is as follows. I have two projects in one solution.

**First project:** Scaffolded through Visual Studio. It is an ASP.NET Core Web Application with authentication for individual user accounts. It has different controllers acting as APIs (which is also scaffolded through Visual Studio). This project is using the repository pattern and I have interfaces which I inject in the projects Startup-file. I am using the latest version of Entity Framework Core to talk to the databse (MSSQL). This project also has all the entity-classes which has built the database through code-first-migrations. The output type of this project is set to Class Library. The following two images shows one of the controllers and the startup-file.

[image: Relevant part of the startup-file]

[image: One of the controllers]

**Second project:** Also scaffolded through Visual Studio. It is an ASP.Net Core SPA (Angular) based on the following: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal. This project is the web app which the user visits and connects to. I want to make calls from this project to the database through the Apis in the previous project. In the future a mobile app which will be developed will also communicate to the same Apis. How do I achieve this in the best way? At the moment I do the following (which works):

1. I have added a reference to the previous project in this project.
2. I have made sure that the startup-file in this project is almost identical to the one in the other project. It wouldnt work without doing this. The error was related to failed dependency injections.
3. I have made sure that the connection-string added in the previous project is also added in this (in the appsettings.json-file).

[image: Relevant part of the startup-file]

What would you do? Would you do anything differently?

Regards,
M.

Comment: "I have added a reference to the previous project in this project." Why? Are webapi's not supposed to be hosted separately and accessed via URL?

Comment: I really don't know. I just did what seemed natural to me. Is this something you recommend?

Comment: Generally, they can be in same solution for coding purposes but published and deployed separately, urls are different. You mentioned output of first project is class library. How do you wish to deploy webapi?

Comment: Okey. This seems much more sensible. Thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: @Amit "How do you wish to deploy webapi?" I am not quite sure what I should answer to that question. I dont have a preference. I have a goal and a vision though. And that is that the project with the Apis will be shared by the Web app and the future Mobile app. Everything will be hosted in the same server. What you suggested before seems good. I will host the two projects separately.